# Add Javascript for cms_index_index only via local.xml

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, javascript

Why can't I add js directly via local.xml but instead have to enter it in the backend cms layout tab? I can reference head in , so for example this will work:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>canonical</rel><href>http://www.domain.com/</href><action>
</reference>
```

While this won't:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.slides.js"></name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.carouFredSel.js"></name><params/></action>
</reference>
```

Is this behavior intended?
Thank you!

Comment: you are using the `cms_index_index` layout handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was `<name>js/jquery.slides.js"></name>` should be  `<name>js/jquery.slides.js"</name>`
Here the complete code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <cms_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
         <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.slides.js</name><params/></action>
         <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.carouFredSel.js</name><params/></action>
    </reference>
  </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is bug in your code. Try this code

```
<reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.slides.js</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.carouFredSel.js</name><params/></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: How did I not see this...
Thank you so much!

I chose Amits answer as the top one, as he elaborates on the issue somewhat more ;)